Looking for young adult/childrens books about a boy traveling through a portal to a fantasy land
I read this book as a kid in about 2008-2012 and have been searching for it for years. Here's what I remember:
A boy travels through a portal he found (in a back alley somewhere?). He comes out in a kind of colder/winter land and meets a guy who was the personification of wind (?) or something. He helps the boy travel forward to the next city and then adventures ensue, etc. (I don’t really remember the rest).
What I do remember very specifically is the next book (or it might’ve been the third installment I’m not sure).
It’s set in a kind of underground cave system area, where the main character and a girl he meets in the first book have to travel to get some kind of Macguffin, or meet someone. They meet up with some kind of dwarf people who live down in these caves and there's a sequence where they have to crawl through a  tunnel that gets progressively tighter. I remember there being a dwarf/enslaved (?) civilization down there. They had to get through the caves without being discovered by them or something. At the end they end up in this big room filled with water and find a way out through there somehow.
I also remember something with the main character being in a big room with lots of portals, one of them leading to an evil hell dimension and he had to make an important decision there.
The cover of the cave book had a drawing of it on the front, there were no people on it, just a big underground canyon, with some ruins in the middle, the stones were reddish in color.
I hope someone here can help me out I’ve been looking for these books for years.

Welcome to SFF.SE Mae! I like all the details you provided in your question. :)

Faintly reminiscent of The Underland Chronicles by Suzanne Collins https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Underland_Chronicles. Unfortunately, most of the details don't match.
